# Why doesn't redux saga continue after fetch promise resolves?

Tags: react-redux, es6-promise, fetch-api, redux-saga

I have a request function that returns a promise. response.json(). My Issue is that although it resolves, but my loadData function does not continue past my call.

```
export function* loadData() {
  console.log("Saga: Loading Data...");
  try {
    const response = yield call(request, requestURL,
    { method: 'GET', credentials: 'include', headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', }  });
    // Nothing past this point is ever touched :(
    if (response.success) {
     console.log("SUCCESS!!!!");
     ...

export default function request(url, options) {
  return fetch(url, options)
    .then(checkStatus)
    .then(parseJSON);
}
```

CheckStatus confirms a successful status on the data

```
function parseJSON(response) {
  if (response.status === 204 || response.status === 205) {
    return null;
  }
  var responseClone = response.clone();
  console.log(responseClone.json());
  return response.json();
}
```

When I run it, the console outputs the following. Confirming that my promise is resolving with the data I want. But the code still does not continue. Only does once every 50 or so tries.

```
SAGA: Loading Data...
[[PromiseStatus]]:"resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]:Object
```